# Passing info from AppDelegate to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have an app that is receiving data from a deep link in the AppDelegate. I want to send that data to one of my ViewControllers. I'm using `self.window?.rootViewController` but I don't know how that behaves. How should I accomplish this?

**My AppDelegate.swift**

`import UIKit`
`import CoreData`

`@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {`

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    println(url)
    //This is where I need to change the value of testval
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    self.saveContext()
}

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.xxxx.WhenISay" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as! NSURL
    }()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("UserData", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("WhenISay.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
    }()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

`}`

`

**My FeedViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

public class FeedViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var feedView: UIWebView!

public var testval = String()

override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

    var feedURL = NSURL(string: "http://whensayfeed.meteor.com")

    if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR == 1 {
        feedURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000")
        println("In Development")
    }

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: feedURL!)
    feedView.loadRequest(request)
    feedView.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal
}

override public func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    feedView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
}

override public func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
}

override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

`}`

Comment: " I'm using `self.window?.rootViewController` but I don't know how that behaves." Well, your first stop should be the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController).

Comment: What have you tried? How well is your understanding of Swift? How well is your understand go the iOS SDK?

Comment: You can create a reference to your `AppDelegate` like so: `let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this I can come up with:

1 use NSUserDefaults, store your info and read it later with corresponding methods:

`setBool`, `setObject`, etc

2 Use NSNotification mechanism to send it

3 Create appDelegate Object so you have access to public properties and variables,

borrow the code from the comment:

`let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate`

you can access it by `appDelegate`

Comment: How could this be done using just the class of the ViewController such as: viewcontroller.variable = "value"?

Comment: you add a property 'value' or whatever for "value" in your appDelegate header file or via protocol or via notification, and in your view controller, you use appDelegate.value or protocol or notification and you get your "value" now

Comment: I'm very new. I hate to say that I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: If you want to set viewcontroller.variable = "value" in your appDelegate, that is simple, create your viewcontroller object and assign it. like `UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController alloc] init]; vc.variable = "value"`

Comment: if you are very new, google and get yourself warmed up about the words you don't understand.

Comment: You just use swift to do what I mentioned, they are shared

Comment: I'm sure that code explains it perfectly but I don't know that language

Comment: Can you translate this `UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController alloc] init];

Comment: var vc = UIViewController(); vc.variable = 'some value'

Comment: dude, you really need to walk through swift first if you don't understand what I am talking about

Comment: If I'm supposed to replace UIViewController() with my viewcontoller class name then I've tried that and it says that my view controller doesn't have that value. Btw I have declared the var in my class as type String

Comment: paste your viewcontroller class code if possible. You need to make sure your property is public so you can access it externally. check https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82

Comment: I'm not at my computer currently but I have a hunch that you are right

Comment: again, you should walk through swift first. It feels you are not even know OOP quite well.

Comment: You're right, I have to keep working on swift. I'm originally a web developer so I'm very familiar with JS

Comment: all right, that should make it easy to master swift. The link I provide for swift can help a lot.

Comment: I added my code to the question. As you can see I think I made everything in my viewcontroller public.